# Choosing cloud database for Flutter project

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, nosql

I am creating a Recipe App on Flutter where it will hold recipes and I am here to humbly ask for suggestions on which Cloud Database should I be using to integrate with my app? I will list down few of the things that I would be expecting the Cloud Database to handle for my app, maybe from the listed requirements may help you guys better in suggesting one.

Requirements:

- Users needs to login to use the app, so that the user can post their own Recipes to the Cloud Database.
- Users can publish some photos to post for their recipes (was considering to store google drive links).
- Users can see any recipes that are posted by other users.
- Users can favorite a recipe and keep it in their list.
- Users can comment on a recipe and give stars rating on it.
- Users can view comments of a recipe that is written by others.
- Users will be able to search for a recipe and while searching, they can also apply one or more filters such as Cuisine Types, Rating Stars and other filters that may be applicable.

Initially I was thinking to go with Firebase for creating projects with Flutter, considering the fact that I need to have User logins and No-SQL Database seems to be the best option for me to stick with when coming to Recipes and User reviews. However the problem here is, I am unsure if Firebase can perform the multi filter searches. The query has to be flexible as I may perform searches with different filter parameters.

Comment: Making recommendations for off-site technology is off-topic on Stack Overflow. For the types of queries you can do with Firestore, have a look at https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries and https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ofux_4c94FI

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you had made up your mind with flutter. so i will suggest you to go with `Cloud-firestore`. it ticks all your requirements.
Also, it has really good support with flutter.

Comment: Any idea how can firestore be used to do multi-param search?